# How does the multiplication law creates order?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question :

There are $2n$ students divided to couples to do homework.

Using the multiply law we can choose the first couple then the second then the third couple and so on. 
The order is not important and there are no returns, therefore :

$$A =\binom {2n}2 *\binom {2n-2}2*...*\binom {2}2$$

I don't understand why I should divide $A$ by $n!$ in order to get the right answer, In the lecture it said because we use the multiplication law and therefore there is order between the couples, yet I don't understand how did impose order between the couples?

For example let take n=2, assume Eric,John,Liza,Tina are students, we choose 2 of them and tell them to sit down and do their homework, assume Eric,Tina were chosen as a couple, now we choose John and Liza, tell them to sit down and do their homework, I don't see any order between the couples here.

Any help will be be dearly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If $n = 4$, then $2n = 8$.  You really chose $n = 2$.  See what happens if $n = 3$.  Also, you should have $\binom{2n}{2}\binom{2n - 2}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2}$.

Comment: My bad, I'll edit, What's different in case of $n=3$? Assume 1,2,3,4,5,6 are students we choose 2 of them assume we chose 1,2 as a couple hence we are left with 3,4,5,6, now we choose 2 out of 4 assume 3,4 is a couple hence we are left with 5,6, so we choose 5,6 as a couple, where did I impose order between the couples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the order you pick the couples in, it's what the final pairing is.

So in the case $n=3$, picking $12,34,56$ is the same as picking $34,12,56$ or any other combination of $12,34$ and $56$, just as long as you pick **those** couples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is it true to look at this in the following way?  for n=3 each we get $$\binom n2 *\binom {n-2}2*\binom {2}2$$ each $\binom nk$ give as a couple but since multiply is commutative get $12,34,56$ is the same as picking $34,12,56$ because of the commutative of $\binom{nk}?

Comment: yes- we pick the first two, etc.., without repeats

Comment: and N.F.Taussig is right, you should have 2n in the binomial

Comment: Edited for future people, coming across this question, Thank you for your help:)